# What is the meaning of the phrase "for all someone is concerned"?

Tags: meaning

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/FTrxX0b4I4o). It is at 6 minute and 51 second.

> If you want to talk about an offer at home first, it is never okay for a company to ask who you are talking to. You could talk to your cat **for all they are concerned**.

I was looking for the phrase's definition on the internet, but I couldn't find anything. Only phrases like *as far as one is concerened* crop up, which I can understand. What does the *for all* in the phrase mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a very common phrase in my opinion. However, I do understand it to be synonymous with the following, more common, phrase:

> You could talk to your cat **for all they care**.

[Here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for-all-sb-cares-knows) is a definition of the phrase I have used above.

Essentially, the author is saying that the do not mind who you talk to about the offer, it's not secret. You may discuss it at home with your family and friends.

Answer (score 0):

*For all (that)* is used in speech (not often in writing) to mean *irrespective*, or *even though*. (I think that part of the reason it is not often used in writing is that it is easy to mis-parse, especially when "that" is omitted).

So here the meaning is *irrespective of what they know or think*. The implication is that it is none of their business.